# How to insert 9 billions records into a database in 2 minutes?

Tags: sql, database, caching, nosql, distributed-system

I have to insert 9 billions records with a timestamp field into a database in 2~3 minutes. These records will be queried by time range later. So what database should I use in this situation?

Comment: In some databases, you can switch the files used for the database.  This is highly technical and database dependent.  Otherwise, you need lots and lots and lots of hardware.

Comment: This project has budget for hundreds of hardware server, but it will take several months to purchase.  For now I have to do technology selection for this point. I think NoSQL database maybe good at this, but the need for range query is difficult for many databases...